How to define a torchrl policy where the allowable actions depend on the environment state?
I'm training a model to play a particular card game (a variant of poker).  At each player's turn, the set of acceptable moves will be a set (possibly empty) of subsets of the cards they hold.  I am encoding the current hand and the move as a vector of 52 bools.
        hand = torch.zeros(self.batch_size + ( 52, ), dtype=torch.bool)

and the action_spec (for the move):
        self.action_spec = BinaryDiscreteTensorSpec(52, dtype=torch.bool)

The particular list of acceptable moves for the player is available from the custom environment I've written for this game.  For example, here is the rand_action method (for brevity I've stripped out some error checking):

    def rand_action(self, tensordict: TensorDictBase | None = None) -> TensorDictBase:
        if tensordict is not None:
            shape = tensordict.shape
        elif not self.batch_size:
            shape = torch.Size([])
        moves = []
        for i in range(self.total_batch_size()):
            game = self.games[i]
            game_moves = game.getMoves()
            game_move = game_moves[np.random.randint(len(game_moves))]
            moves.append([bool(i in game_move) for i in range(52)])
        if len(self.batch_size) == 0:
            r = TensorDict({"action": torch.tensor(moves[0], dtype=torch.bool)}, 
                               batch_size=self.batch_size)
        else:
            r = TensorDict({"action": torch.tensor(moves, dtype=torch.bool)}, batch_size=self.batch_size)
        if tensordict is None:
            return r
        tensordict.update(r)
        return tensordict

I'd like to define a Q-function that maps State x Vect(52) -> Values. The policy will choose the best one from the list of allowable actions returned by the environment.
My question is: how to define a Q-learning policy for this in torchrl?  The standard QValueActor and QValueModule classes seem to pick a particular best action (argmax) out of a pre-defined list of actions.
I've read through the torchrl documentation and examples available, but they all seem to rely on an action space which is pre-defined.  I cannot find any examples where the space could be a particular list of subsets of a fix set, for example.

Your QValue model will have a fixed output size. The output size should contain all possible actions in your environment. To select from a subset of actions based on the current game state, you want to mask the illegal/invalid actions before selecting your Q value. The QValueModule has a action_mask_key parameter which lets you pass a mask along with action values

Thank you Karl.   I don't think that this would work well for my case, however.  The issue is that the acceptable set of moves (they have to be actual poker hands, and there are other state-specific constraints).  The entire space of potential moves would be enormous, something like 2^52 or 52 choose 5 which is about 2.5 million.

You're confusing the game space with agent actions. Your actions are the list of things your agent can actually do. For example a simple poker agent would have Check/Call/Raise/Bet/Fold. You could make that more refined by adding several categories for "bet x% of the pot". If your game involves picking cards from the agent hand, that would be "select card i" where i is the index in the hand.

I'm a bit confused.  An action is to play a subset of the hand.  The initial hands have 13 cards, so I could use a 2^13 = 8192 dim 1-hot vector to represent this, and using the action_mask_key to whittle this down to legal moves. It's more complicated than just playing 1 card, as the combinations of cards that are allowed depend on each other and the state of the game (e.g. straight verus pair, and depends on what the previous player played).
Is there a way to use BinaryDiscreteTensorSpec and only allow a list of those in the action space?  Introducing a 8192 dim vector seems inefficient.

You can just use a learned embedding for each card/suit. There's no reason to use one hot encoding with DL models (matmul with a one-hot vector is just an inefficient embedding lookup). Instead of thinking about every possible action, think about classes of actions. You can check out this library for examples of converting games into action spaces
